# Blank Taskbar Mate Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate

I get blank white bars on the top and bottom when I try to run mate in Ubuntu 15.10.  Does anyone know what might cause this?  Alternatively, is anyone running mate on 15.10 successfully and what was your approach?

Even if I click where a menu should be, there is no response so I think it is more than just a rendering issue.

Not sure of etiquette, `.xsession-errors` is here:

http://pastebin.com/n6us12E6

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the `mate-panel --reset` command in a terminal will sometimes fix this problem.

Comment: That makes sense.  Though, with a problem of this nature I think it's difficult for people to be sure their answer will solve it.  He may have just been expressing that added level of uncertainty.  Happily, it worked great.